# Swipe Back Activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I am using swipe back activity in one of my project activity.

[Demo Project Which I have implemented](https://github.com/liuguangqiang/SwipeBack)

My activity layout contains recyclerview and other components as well. So the problem is when I scroll up my recyclerview items then activity get finished.

However it is working perfectly in Listview.

So is there any way to prevent activity to finish while recyclerview is scrolling ?

Comment: Is demo working? Need your code to help out.

Comment: yes demo is working perfectly.the only issue is i have to use recyclerview in my activity and when it scrolls down activity gets finish rather than scrolling recyclerview. I want to scroll recyclerview instead of finishing the activity.

Comment: Just add your code for recycler view and it's related adapter and xml, may be issue in adapter related work.

Comment: I have solved the issue. Now i have added swipeback layout to my xml rather than creating it dynamically from java file and overlaped my recyclerview over it using relative layout. so it will consider touch of recyclerview primarily.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding a scroll listener.

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int firstVisibleItem = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if (firstVisibleItem == 0) {
                    setEnableSwipe(true);
                } else {
                    setEnableSwipe(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

I don't know if this is the best solution. But it works  :)